# How to use a viewstate'd object as a datasource for controls on a user control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, viewstate

I've got a listview on a control.  Each row comprises a checkbox and another listview.

The outer listview is bound to a property on the control (via a method call, can't set a property as a SelectMethod on an ObjectDataSource it would appear)  which is lazy loaded suchly:

```
    Public ReadOnly Property ProductLineChargeDetails() As List(Of WebServiceProductLineChargeDetail)
    Get
        If ViewState("WSProductLineChargeDetails") Is Nothing Then
            ViewState("WSProductLineChargeDetails") = GetWebServiceProductLineChargeDetails()
        End If

        Return DirectCast(ViewState("WSProductLineChargeDetails"), Global.System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Global.MI.Open.WebServiceProductLineChargeDetail))
    End Get
End Property
```

The shape of the object referenced by the data source is something like this:

(psuedocode)

```
Product
{
 bool Licenced;
 List<Charge> charges;
}

Charge
{
 int property1;
 string property2;
 bool property3
 .
 .
 .
}
```

The reason for the use of viewstate is this:

When an one of the checkboxes on one of the outer list view rows is checked or unchecked I want to  modify the object that the ODS represents (for example I'll add a couple of Charge objects to the relevant Product object) and then rebind.

The problem I'm getting is that after every postback (specifically after checking or unchecking one of the rows' checkbox) my viewstate is empty.  Thiss means that any changes I make to my viewstate'd object is lost.

Now, I've worked out (after much googling and reading, amongst many others, Scott Mitchel's excellent bit on ViewState) that during initial databinding **IsTrackingViewState** is set to false.  That means, I think, that assigning the return from GetWebServiceProductLineChargeDetails() to the ViewState item in my Property Get during the initial databind won't work.

Mind you, even when the **IsTrackingViewState** is true and I call the Property Get, come the next postback, the viewstate is empty.

So do you chaps have any ideas on how I keep the object referenced by the ObjectDataSource in ViewState between postbacks and update it and get those changes to stay in ViewState?  This has been going on for a couple of days now and I'm getting fed up!

Cheers in advance

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for changes to be tracked in the viewstate the object must be assigned to the viewstate when IsTrackingViewState is True.  Viewstate starts tracking after Init in the pagelifecycle.  You are probably binding too early for the objects to be stored in viewstate.  You should bind the list view after the Init stage, probably in the load stage.

i.e.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ListView.DataSource = ProductLineChargeDetails
    ListView.DataBind
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes well, that's certainly going to be something I'm going to have to sort out.  Problem is, even when IsTrackingViewState is true (in a CheckedChanged event handler), I've gone and modified the object behind the ODS, and the changes are definately reflected in ViewState and then after a postback, there's nothing in ViewState.

Comment: Oh hang on, I've just re-read that.  So the object has to be _assigned_ after ViewState changes are being tracked?  Ah yes, that makes sense.

Comment: When are you checking after the postback?  They should be there after the control hits its load event.  If not then there are other problems.

Comment: I did have an other problem with rebinding in the wrong place but now binding programtically in the load has solved everything.  You gotta know the lifecycle pretty well to get any non-trivial data binding to work don't you? Thanks for the help.  Now I'm only going to be 4 days late! :)

Comment: Yeah you do have to get a pretty good idea of the lifecycle for asp.  It's always full of surprises for you